# How to test a PowerApps Custom Connector GET request at localhost?

Tags: powerapps

I have a test environment at http://localhost:3000/ and I want to check the GET requests coming from this localhost URL.

I get the following error. Installing the service in an Asure/ AWS environment can be a solution. But I want to know whether there is an option in PowerApps that we can use to test localhost requests.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing this through an On-Premises Gateway? Refer to <https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/on-premise-apis/>

Comment: Thanks. I created a gateway as mentioned in the link. But it didn't show in the Gateways section in the Powerapps. Anyway, we installed in an Azure VM and could work.

Comment: @Subhashi having the same. Have you managed to work with localhost?

Comment: @DavidMeu I don't really remember what I exactly did as it's been a long time. But we created this help page for our product using what we did (Not sure whether it helps, but sending it to you anyway).
 https://resource.flexrule.com/knowledge-base/execute-using-powerapps/